# adding plugin dataTable to dynamic created table HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, datatable

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            //$.ajaxSetup({async:false});
            $.post("/inner.html",function(data){
                $("#content").append("<div><table id='example' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='display'></table></div>");
                $("#example").html(data);
                var tabl = $("#exapmle").dataTable();
                //tabl.fnDraw();
                //tabl.fnClearTable(tabl);
                //tabl.fnAddData(data);
                //tabl.fnReloadAjax("/inner.html");
            },"html");

html

<div id="content"></div>
```

inner.html return next data

```
<!--<div>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">-->
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 4.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">4</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 5.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+</td>
            <td class="center">5.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet
                 Explorer 6</td>
            <td>Win 98+</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
            <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
            <td class="center">7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Trident</td>
            <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
            <td>Win XP</td>
            <td class="center">6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 2.0</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Firefox 3.0</td>
            <td>Win 2k+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.9</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.0</td>
            <td>OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Camino 1.5</td>
            <td>OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape 7.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / Mac OS 8.6-9.2</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Browser 8</td>
            <td>Win 98SE+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Netscape Navigator 9</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.2</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.2</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.3</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.4</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.4</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.6</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.6</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.7</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.7</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Mozilla 1.8</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Seamonkey 1.1</td>
            <td>Win 98+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Gecko</td>
            <td>Epiphany 2.20</td>
            <td>Gnome</td>
            <td class="center">1.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.2</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">125.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 1.3</td>
            <td>OSX.3</td>
            <td class="center">312.8</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 2.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">419.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>Safari 3.0</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">522.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>OmniWeb 5.5</td>
            <td>OSX.4+</td>
            <td class="center">420</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>iPod Touch / iPhone</td>
            <td>iPod</td>
            <td class="center">420.1</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Webkit</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td>S60</td>
            <td class="center">413</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.1+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 7.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 8.5</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.2+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.0</td>
            <td>Win 95+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.2</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera 9.5</td>
            <td>Win 88+ / OSX.3+</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Opera for Wii</td>
            <td>Wii</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nokia N800</td>
            <td>N800</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Presto</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS browser</td>
            <td>Nintendo DS</td>
            <td class="center">8.5</td>
            <td class="center">C/A<sup>1</sup></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.1</td>
            <td>KDE 3.1</td>
            <td class="center">3.1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.3</td>
            <td>KDE 3.3</td>
            <td class="center">3.3</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>KHTML</td>
            <td>Konqureror 3.5</td>
            <td>KDE 3.5</td>
            <td class="center">3.5</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 4.5</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-9</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.1</td>
            <td>Mac OS 7.6-9</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Tasman</td>
            <td>Internet Explorer 5.2</td>
            <td>Mac OS 8-X</td>
            <td class="center">1</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.1</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeA">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>NetFront 3.4</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Dillo 0.8</td>
            <td>Embedded devices</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Links</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeX">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>Lynx</td>
            <td>Text only</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>IE Mobile</td>
            <td>Windows Mobile 6</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeC">
            <td>Misc</td>
            <td>PSP browser</td>
            <td>PSP</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gradeU">
            <td>Other browsers</td>
            <td>All others</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td class="center">-</td>
            <td class="center">U</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Rendering engine</th>
            <th>Browser</th>
            <th>Platform(s)</th>
            <th>Engine version</th>
            <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
<!--</table>
</div>-->
```

But plugin still not work if same data created in static page all work fine
How adding plugin to dynamic created table(html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go through this discussion may be helpful to you...[try this](http://datatables.net/forums/comments.php?DiscussionID=990)

and it will be better if you post this question to dataTable forum...[Datatable Forum](http://datatables.net/forums/?page=1)

Comment: I think we're being told that an upvote is at least as good as a thanks... http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#example').live('click', function() {
```

I'm aware you're not clicking anything but this is the basic principle, you need to use .live() as this will work with dynamically created elements :)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close the `document.ready` function, use `});` at the end of the your script. And if `inner.html` is in the same directory, then do not use `/.`, just use  `$.post("inner.html", ...`.

Comment: The url was changet to post questions . ajax request and responce work fine! second block show responce on ajax.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably pretty old -- anyways...

Theres a simple typo in the code

```
$("#content").append("<div><table id='example' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' class='display'></table></div>");
            $("#example").html(data);
            var tabl = $("#exapmle").dataTable();
            //tabl.fnDraw();
```

emphasis on:
`var tabl = $("#exapmle").dataTable();`